# Unsubscribe multiple firestore snapshots VueJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

What is the right way to unsubscribe to multiple snapshots in vuejs?

I have multiple components, and most of them have a snapshot to take advantage of firebase real time sync, the logout function is located in a navbar component, but once I logout from firebase, I got an error because I’m not unsubscribing from my snapshots, but how can I do this if all of them are on different components?

Is there a way to unsubscribe all snapshots at once?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: You could look at the *beforeDestroy* life cycle hook: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy

Comment: @Marcel in this part of the lifecycle did I have access to all components? Or once I trigger the logout function this lifecycle runs on each component? How can I make them unsubscribe before the checkout is done? Have any example I can see? Thanks in advance

Comment: The idea is that you add this to all components where you subscribe, and within this you unsubscribe from your snapshots used in that component. So when you navigate away from the component these subscriptions will be destroyed.

Comment: @Marcel I’m gonna try this way, you are right, it sounds logical xD

Comment: @Marcel, worked just great, i just added the variable to this.$root.snapshots, and then i call them on the beforeDestroy() lifecicle, and worked perfectly, please add your answer to accept it! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unsubscribe from a snapShot, you can use *beforeDestroy*. This gets called whenever you navigate away from this component. Inside you can call methods for unsubscribing from your snapShots.

For more information, see the Vue.js docs.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy